# CSS background color propery does not work

Tags: html, css

I am building a website in html and css, and I got a problem.
This is my code:

Everything works, except the background-color property.That does not work.

I have tried every answer from past answers, but I can't fix this.

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #00b36b
  padding: 10px;
  color: #1ac6ff;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

The background color should have been ##00b36b, but it isn't.

Comment: Looks like you are missing `;` at the end of `background-color: #00b36b`

Comment: Oh my god I am so stupid.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing semi-colons have been added to background-color and color. They must be at the end of every CSS value. Type below code:

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #00b36b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #1ac6ff;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `;` at the end of `background-color: #00b36b`

Try the following:-

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
  background-color: #00b36b;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #1ac6ff;
  text-align: right;
  overflow: auto;
}
```